# Corrupted migration?

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration

The following question was migrated from Stack Overflow:

[iTunesConnect Error: “Unknown app version”](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/251907/itunesconnect-error-unknown-app-version)

The source of the migration is a revision of an answer.

What gives?

Comment: We're investigating this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has been resolved. We were performing some testing on Post Notices and in doing so we found this bug in the migration process.

This bug has been fixed and there should be no more weird migrations that point to incorrect posts.